# Screen occasionally autoscrolling

Tags: touchpad, security, scrolling

Ubuntu 20.04

From past couple of days, my screen autoscrolls randomly. Its like scrolls then waits, then scrolls.

The interesting thing is it keeps happening for a few seconds even when I turn off the touchpad and disconnect mouse.

I scanned all files with ClamTk but most were Libre and imurmurhash related warnings.
Would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks & Regards.